# How nested query in Elasticsearch works?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

The question will be a bit lengthy, but I hope you can take a look and give me some hints on what could be the problem:

I have a mapping:

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "sections": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "foo": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "sentences": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "entities": {
                                    "type": "nested",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "has_props": {
                                            "type": "nested",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "some_string": {
                                                    "type": "keyword"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "bar": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "sentences": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "entities": {
                                    "type": "nested",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "has_props": {
                                            "type": "nested",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "some_string": {
                                                    "type": "keyword"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a document to be indexed:

```json
{
    "sections": {
        "foo": {
            "sentences": [
                {
                    "entities": {
                        "has_props": {
                            "some_string": "END"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "bar": {
            "sentences": [
                {
                    "entities": {
                        "has_props": {
                            "some_string": "END"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a nested query like this:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "sections.foo.sentences.entities",
            "query": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "sections.bar.sentences.entities.has_props",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "sections.bar.sentences.entities.has_props.some_string"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I know the query is syntactically correct, but it should not return anything because I try to query a different nested path (`sections.bar.sentences.entities`) within another one (`sections.foo.sentences.entities`). So far so good, it returns empty set as I expected, even if I switch the two paths (`*.bar.*` inside, and `*.foo.*` outside), it returns me an empty set also. <= Please note this point.

Now, what I need is a little bit more dynamic, it means I could have other properties, not just `foo`, `bar`. So instead of a static mapping, I will use dynamic templates:

```json
{
    "dynamic_templates": [
        {
            "section_nested": {
                "path_match": "sections.*",
                "match_mapping_type": "object",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "entities_nested": {
                "path_match": "sections.*.*",
                "match_mapping_type": "object",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "sentences": {
                "path_match": "*.sentences",
                "match_mapping_type": "object",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "has_props": {
                "path_match": "*.has_props",
                "match_mapping_type": "object",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "nested_has_props": {
                "path_match": "*.has_props.*",
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "properties": {
        "sections": {
            "type": "nested"
        }
    }
}
```

I delete, re-create the index, update the mapping, and then re-index the same document as above. When I try to get the mapping after indexing the document, it gives me a similar mapping to the static one:

```json
GET /dummy/_mapping
{
  "dummy": {
    "mappings": {
       "dynamic_templates": [...],
       "properties": {
        "sections": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "bar": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "sentences": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                    "entities": {
                      "type": "nested",
                      "properties": {
                        "has_props": {
                          "type": "nested",
                          "properties": {
                            "some_string": {
                              "type": "keyword"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "foo": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "sentences": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                    "entities": {
                      "type": "nested",
                      "properties": {
                        "has_props": {
                          "type": "nested",
                          "properties": {
                            "some_string": {
                              "type": "keyword"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The mapping returned is generated by the dynamic templates above. So, I expected the behavior should be the same as the static mapping above. But here, the weird thing happens, and I don't know what I have done is wrong. For the same query above:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "sections.foo.sentences.entities",
            "query": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "sections.bar.sentences.entities.has_props",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "sections.bar.sentences.entities.has_props.some_string"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This returns empty, so correct. **BUT**, if I switch the path, it gives me the document:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "sections.bar.sentences.entities",
            "query": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "sections.foo.sentences.entities.has_props",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "sections.foo.sentences.entities.has_props.some_string"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am confused. I appreciate if anyone could give me some explanations, or could point out my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).